# Laravel store Files from API with specific folder creation

Tags: php, laravel, post, store

My goal is create Laravel API to store Files, from VSTO POST request. But first need figure out how create unigue folders in laravel where to file store.

From VSTO sending POST with `File` and parameter `id_message`. How to set Laravel Controller to store file as `storage/app/MyFiles/{id_message}/file`, and parametr `id_message` wile `file_path` save to database table ?

`FileController`

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
    function fileUpload(Request $request)
    {

    $request->validate([
        'id_message' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    $input = $reguest->all();
    
    $result=$request->file('file')->store('MyFiles');
    return ["result"=>$result];
```

Update

for someone who need clue:

```
function fileUpload(Request $request)
{
    //$fileFromApi=storage_path('app/apiFiles/');
    $request->validate([
        'id_message' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    
    $idParameter = $request->id_message=$request->id_message;

    $result=$request->file('file')->store('MyFiles/'.$idParameter);
    return ["result"=>$result];
```

Comment: you can try `Storage::put("foldername",$request->file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `store()` you can use `storeAs()` try this:

```php
$file = $request->file('file')->storeAs($filepath, $filename, $driver);
```

Comment: my bad, your answer take me to right way. this works ````$idParameter = $request->id_message=$request->id_message;```` and file ````$result=$request->file('file')->store('apiFiles/'.$idParameter);````

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
$result=$request->file('file')->store('MyFiles/'.id_message);
```

Comment: storage_path ````storage/app/MyFiles/```` working, what i need create new folder ````storage/app/MyFiles/{id_message}/```` and store file here