# Laravel Receipt pdf download

Tags: php, laravel, invoice, receipt

I'm using `laraveldaily/laravel-invoices` to generate invoices.

I've stored the receipt with `->save('public');` and stored this link to database with: `$invoice->url()`.

I got a link like this: `http://example.com/storage/pdf_name.pdf` .
But, File stored in `storage/app/public/` folder

Now, If I hit this URL, it says `**"Forbidden"** You don't have permission to access this resource.`

**What can I do now? and is there any way to store just folder and file name? like: `folder/pdf_name.pdf`**

Comment: You can read laravel documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel store Files from API with specific folder creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443186/laravel-store-files-from-api-with-specific-folder-creation)

Comment: @gguney I've checked your suggested question. But, it's not the answer to my question.

Comment: Did you read laravel documentation?

Comment: @gguney I've read Laravel's "File Storage" official documentation. Now my error has been solved.